# require_once failed to find file

Tags: php

I try to use my own classes in the ratchet main class but I fail at the require_once

See the image of my files structure.

[image]

Comment: not working, same error

Comment: try: `../vendor/UserManager.php`

Comment: Try using an autoloader instead of using relative references for includes/reqires

Comment: Try using `require_once __DIR__.'/../../UserManager.php'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `require_once __DIR__.'/../../UserManager.php'`

@dasdasd here is my commented converted into an answer... thanks ;)

Comment: Now I got another problem the require does not work.
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MyApp\UserManager' not found in /var/www/metalCheck/src/MyApp/Chat.php on l                        ine 21

Comment: What is your PHP version? And what is on line 21? The pic does not show.

Comment: PHP 5.4. In this line I have UserManager::getUserPartyId($querystring);

Comment: Well then, it has to do with namespaces. On line 21 you invoke a class from current namespace (MyApp), so you must make sure that the UserManager class is define for same namespace.

Comment: If I dont want to use namespaces? Is there a way to not use it?